# last element in array not appear, when print array after add two elements get array with one element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

Hi I am try to delete element from array but when click on delete for last element I get array with allelements except last element and if click on first element get empty array only any one know the reason

`another problem` if I console.log the array of element directly after add I get all elements exception last one to that if I print array after first add I get empty array

add Function

```
const [mcqAnswerList, setMcqAnswerList] = useState<any[]>([]);
const handleCreateMcqQuestion = () => {
        setMcqAnswerList(
            mcqAnswerList.concat({
                question: (
                    <McqQuestion
                        key={ids}
                        good={ids}
                        mcqAnswerList={mcqAnswerList}
                        setMcqAnswerList={setMcqAnswerList}
                    />
                ),
                id: ids,
            })
        );
    };
```

add button

```
<button
    className="text-[#4E73F8]"
    onClick={() => {
        handleCreateMcqQuestion();
        setIds((prev: number) => prev + 1);
    }}>
    + {`${t("add another one")}`}
</button>
```

delete button

```
<div
    className="mx-[7px] w-[80px] cursor-pointer"
    onClick={e => {
        handleDeleteMcqQuestion(mcqRef.current.getAttribute("data-id"));
    }}>
    <label id="remove">
        <Remove />
    </label>
</div>
```

`delete function` that return array element an exception last element

```
const handleDeleteMcqQuestion = (id: any) => {
  console.log(mcqAnswerList);
}
```

Comment: Here, mcqAnswerList={mcqAnswerList}, you are assigning previous version of the list, without an object, being concatenated in the same statement. By the way, saving react components in the state isn't a good idea. Consider to store in the state plain objects and render react components from them.

Comment: thank you, I don't understand what do you mean by `store in the state plain objects and render ` can you explain it please

Comment: Is ids a single value or an array?
If it is an array, why did you write like "setIds((prev: number) => prev + 1);"?

Comment: ids is a state, I am try to add id and change this number after click on the button